# Calling C library from NodeJs

Tags: c, node.js, node-ffi

could anyone help me to solve a problem with nodejs and C library (call to some dll methods)?

My dll have these methods:

```
void Open(char *Path);
int Execute(TINData *InData,TOUData *OutData);
void Close(void);
```

with these data structures:

```
typedef struct {
      char Value[8+1];
      char Type [1+1];
      int Id;
      unsigned char Parity;
} TINData

typedef struct {
      char Cash[8+1];
      char Telephone[11+1];
      char CallType[3+1];
      char CallResult[2+1];
      char Description[24+1];
} TOUTData
```

My nodejs code:

```
var ffi = require('ffi');
var ref = require('ref');
var StructType = require('ref-struct');



var TINData = StructType({
      'Value': 'string',
      'Type': 'string',
      'Id': 'int',
      'Parity': 'string'
});

var TOUTData = StructType({
      'Cash': 'string',
      'Telephone': 'string',
      'CallType': 'string',
      'CallResult': 'string',
      'Description': 'string'
});




var mylibrary = ffi.Library('OurLib.dll', {
      'Open' : ['void', ['string']],
      'Execute' : ['void', [TINData, TOUTData]],
      'Close' : ['void', ['void']]
});

myLibrary.Open('myConnection');

var myTINData = new TINData();           
myTINData.Value = '00000010';
myTINData.Type = '1';
myTINData.Id = 123;
myTINData.Parity = '0';



 var myTOUTData = new TOUTData();
    var i = mylibrary.Execute(myTINData, myTOUTData);

    myLibrary.Close();
```

My dll writes all received data into a debug file and I see that data values passed with input object are inserted in wrong positions and I'm not able to read values of the output object.

Where I be in error?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but... here is what I found.

```
var ArrayType = require('ref-array')
```

The declaration of TINData can be like this:

```
var TINData = Struct({
      'Value': ArrayType('char', 9),
      'Type': ArrayType('char', 3),
      'Id': 'int',
      'Parity': 'uchar'
});
```

And for the TOUTData:

```
var TOUTData = Struct({
      'Cash': ArrayType('char', 9),
      'Telephone': ArrayType('char', 12),
      'CallType': ArrayType('char', 4),
      'CallResult': ArrayType('char', 3),
      'Description': ArrayType('char', 25),
});
```

You can also use `'uchar'` instead of `'char'`

And maybe you will need to handle the null terminators.

More examples [here](https://github.com/TooTallNate/ref-struct/blob/master/test/struct.js).